# how to reset setinterval() after clearinterval() in hover and hoverout event?

Tags: jquery

Once `setInterval()` gets started, I hover my element which causes `clearInterval()` to be called. But as I `hoverOut` the element the `setInterval()` is run twice or simply is not run at all!

```
// activated is function what i want to do somthing
var off = setInterval(activated,3000);

$(".tab-content").hover(
() => {
     clearInterval(off);
},
() => {    
     var off = setInterval(activated,3000);        
})
```

Executes twice in three seconds but `clearInterval` is not executed the second time when hovered.

Comment: That smells like an xy problem. What are you trying to achieve? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange behavior must be due to the `var` keyword within the second callback.

In your code, `var` initializes a completely different variable (local to the callback function) an is assigned a new interval instead of updating the reference you expected. This different variable is said to *shadow* the one declared in the immediate parent scope.

What happens is: you hover a 1rst time, off is cleared, then leaving the element with your mouse creates a new interval bound to the local *off* and not the one above. The reference to the recently created interval is lost as the Javascript runtime leaves the callback (once again because *off* is local), in other words, the interval cannot be cleared because you lost the reference. Now every time you enter and leave the element a new interval is created which causes "activated" function to be run almost randomly.

So change your code by removing the var keyword …

```js
// activated is function what i want to do somthing
var off = setInterval(activated,3000);

$(".tab-content").hover(
  () => {
     clearInterval(off);
  },
  () => {    
     off = setInterval(activated,3000);     
  }
)
```

`off` now refers to the `off` declared above the hover call and is not local anymore.

Comment: thanks,actually i was really careless which leaded to this little mistake

Comment: You are welcome, we all need a peer review one day or another. Even when the question author might understand a code only answer, explaining is necessary at least for newcomers to have a good understanding of what was the source of the issue.